# C++ Crypto++ RSA Runtime Crash

Tags: c++, encryption

I have been having issues with a little test I have made in C++. It makes use of the Crypto++ libraries. I have however ran into a few issues with the system with decryption.
When ran in a debuger an invalid ciphertext error comes up. However this cannot be true due to the fact the ciphertext can be decrypted in run time.
I used the VS2015 compiler command line and linking using a static library or .lib file.
Do ignore every thing under private that is not my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// Linked via .lib file with VS2012 console
#include "lib/rsa.h"
#include "lib/modes.h"      
#include "lib/filters.h"
#include "lib/files.h"
#include "lib/hex.h"
#include "lib/randpool.h"
#include "lib/cryptlib.h"
#include "lib/seed.h"
#include "lib/osrng.h"

using namespace CryptoPP;
using namespace std;

class Core
{
private:

    // Pretty much everything under private in this class is from the wiki. So far it all seems to work rather well.
    void Load(const string& filename, BufferedTransformation& bt)
    {
        // http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_source.html
        FileSource file(filename.c_str(), true /*pumpAll*/);

        file.TransferTo(bt);
        bt.MessageEnd();
    }

    void Save(const string& filename, const BufferedTransformation& bt)
    {
        // http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_file_sink.html
        FileSink file(filename.c_str());

        bt.CopyTo(file);
        file.MessageEnd();
    }

    void SavePrivateKey(const string& filename, const PrivateKey& key)
    {
        // http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_byte_queue.html
        ByteQueue queue;
        key.Save(queue);

        Save(filename, queue);
    }

    void SavePublicKey(const string& filename, const PublicKey& key)
    {
        // http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_byte_queue.html
        ByteQueue queue;
        key.Save(queue);

        Save(filename, queue);
    }

    void LoadPrivateKey(const string& filename, PrivateKey& key)
    {
        // http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_byte_queue.html
        ByteQueue queue;

        Load(filename, queue);
        key.Load(queue);    
    }

    void LoadPublicKey(const string& filename, PublicKey& key)
    {
        // http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_byte_queue.html
        ByteQueue queue;

        Load(filename, queue);
        key.Load(queue);    
    }

    // Encode and Decode do what they are labled as
    void encode(string in,string &out,string keyFileName)
    {
        AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
        RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
        LoadPublicKey(keyFileName,publicKey);
        RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);
            StringSource ss1(in, true,
                new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, e,
                    new StringSink(out)
               ) // PK_EncryptorFilter
            ); // StringSource
    }

    void decode(string in,string &out,string keyFileName)
    {
        AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
        RSA::PrivateKey privateKey;
        LoadPrivateKey(keyFileName,privateKey);
        RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor d(privateKey);
        StringSource ss2(in, true,
            new PK_DecryptorFilter(rng, d,
                new StringSink(out)
           ) // PK_DecryptorFilter
        ); // StringSource
    }
public:
    // The title says it all
    void makeKeys()
    {
        AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
        RSA::PrivateKey rsaPrivate;
        rsaPrivate.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(rnd, 3072);

        RSA::PublicKey rsaPublic(rsaPrivate);

        SavePrivateKey("rsa-private.Rkey", rsaPrivate);
        SavePublicKey("rsa-public.Rkey", rsaPublic);
    }
    void encodeFile(string inputFileName,string outputFileName,string keyFileName)
    {

        ofstream Out("theOut",ios::binary);// Test test file
        ifstream fileStreamIn(inputFileName,ios::binary);
        ofstream fileStreamOut(outputFileName,ios::binary);
        size_t read_buffer(342);
        char readBuffer[385];  
        string strBuf1(read_buffer,'\0');
        string cypherBuf("");   
        while(fileStreamIn)
        {
            // Reads and gives sizes
            fileStreamIn.read(readBuffer, read_buffer);

            size_t count = fileStreamIn.gcount();
            // Loads the array into the string
            for(int i = 0; i != read_buffer; i++)
            {
                strBuf1[i] = readBuffer[i];
            }
            strBuf1.resize(count);// Changes for the actual size of the data
            /**/
                cypherBuf.resize(0);
                encode(strBuf1,cypherBuf,keyFileName);
            /**/
            fileStreamOut.write(cypherBuf.c_str(),cypherBuf.length());  

                //This test proves the cypher text
                decode(cypherBuf,strBuf1,"rsa-private.Rkey");

                cout << cypherBuf.length() << "  " << strBuf1.length() << "  " << count << endl;
                Out.write(strBuf1.c_str(),strBuf1.length());

            if (!count) 
                break;  
        }
        fileStreamIn.close();
        fileStreamOut.close();

        Out.close();
    }
    void decodeFile(string inputFileName,string outputFileName,string keyFileName)
    {
        ifstream fileStreamIn(inputFileName,ios::binary);
        ofstream fileStreamOut(outputFileName,ios::binary);
        size_t read_buffer(384);
        char readBuffer[385];  
        string strBuf1(read_buffer+1,'\0');
        string cypherBuf("");   
        while(fileStreamIn)
        {
            // Reads and gives sizes
            fileStreamIn.read(readBuffer, read_buffer);
            size_t count = fileStreamIn.gcount();
            // Loads the array into the string
            cypherBuf = "";
            strBuf1 = "";
            for(int i = 0; i != read_buffer; i++)
            {
                strBuf1[i] = readBuffer[i];
            }
            strBuf1.resize(count);// Changes for the actual size of the data
            // encoder goes here
            /**/
                cypherBuf.resize(0);
                decode(strBuf1,cypherBuf,keyFileName);
                cout << strBuf1.length() << endl;               
                cout << cypherBuf.length() << endl;             
            /**/            
            fileStreamOut.write(cypherBuf.c_str(),cypherBuf.length()); 
            cypherBuf.resize(0);
            if (!count) 
                break;  
        }
        fileStreamIn.close();
        fileStreamOut.close();
    }
};

void main ()
{
    Core Function;

    system("pause");
    Function.encodeFile("in","out","rsa-public.Rkey");
    //Function.decodeFile("out","out1","rsa-private.Rkey"); this line causes a crash

}
```